# IO.FileStream fails when MessageContract changed to DataContract

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wcf, web-services, datacontract

I have a very basic WCF service that receives uploaded documents.  When defined like, it works perfectly:

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface ITransferService

    <OperationContract()>
    <FaultContractAttribute(GetType(MyProcessingFault))>
    Function UploadFile(ByVal request As RemoteFileInfo) As MyWebMethodResult

End Interface

<MessageContract()>
Public Class RemoteFileInfo
    Implements IDisposable

    <MessageHeader(MustUnderstand:=True)>
    Public FileName As String

    <MessageHeader(MustUnderstand:=True)>
    Public Length As Long

    <MessageBodyMember()>
    Public FileByteStream As System.IO.Stream

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        If FileByteStream IsNot Nothing Then
            FileByteStream.Close()
            FileByteStream = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

However, I was a bit confused about using MessageContractAttribute, and most authors suggest keeping things simple with a DataContract instead.  When I change the above to the following however, like this...

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface ITransferService

    <OperationContract()>
    <FaultContractAttribute(GetType(MyProcessingFault))>
    Function UploadFile(ByVal request As RemoteFileInfo) As MyWebMethodResult

End Interface

<DataContract()>
Public Class RemoteFileInfo
    Implements IDisposable

    <DataMember>
    Public FileName As String

    <DataMember>
    Public Length As Long

    <DataMember()>
    Public FileByteStream As System.IO.Stream

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        If FileByteStream IsNot Nothing Then
            FileByteStream.Close()
            FileByteStream = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

I get the following WCF exception when I try to upload to the service:

> **Type 'System.IO.FileStream' with data contract name
>   'FileStream:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.IO' is not
>   expected**

Researching this, I read that streams cannot be serialized, however, surely this must be incorrect for the first example to work?  Is it possible to use a FileStream with a DataContract, or should I not bother even attempting this approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DataContract` messages serialize in a different way than `MessageContract` messages. Having a `Stream` member (thus allowing streaming) must be done using `MessageContract`, wcf then understands it is inteded for streaming and does not try to perform standard serialization.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx for more info:

> You should not be using System.IO.Stream derived types inside of data
>   contracts. Stream data should be communicated using the streaming
>   model, explained in the following "Streaming Data" section.

Comment: Excellent thank you.  I had incorrectly assumed that WCF would apply the correct communication mechanisms based on Object Types used in the service.